# DLL not found in Hololens project. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, hololens

I have created a Unity (2018.2.13f1) project, and I want to add a DLL to get information from an external device thru WiFi to plog information in the HoloLens.

I add the .dll file in the **assets** folder. When I create a script to get info form my costume package and plog it, it recognizes as a reference, and it builds alone.

[image]

but when taring to build in unity, it appears the following

[image]

I tried with other versions of unity, 2017.2.xx and 2017.4.xx but it appeases the same errors.

Comment: Did you add the DLL *to Unity?* Just because you added it to Visual Studio does not mean that the Unity Editor knows about it.

Comment: Yes, I added in the assets. Actually when I create a new C# script it appears automatically in the references.

Comment: I also stuck at this error. So I tried create a simple UWP application that using my custom Dll. The app work fine on the PC but when error when running on HoloLens. Have you find a way to solved this yet?

Comment: I found that it might be a problem with the incompatibilities with .Net versions. Since I do not have access to build, I could not solve the problem and had to change the functionality of my app for the moment. 

In my understanding Unity 2018.1 use .Net 4.6 framework and  2.0 Standard. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to fix this problem too by following [this tutorial](http://mattfedo.com/subpages/hololens_and_ibeacons.html).